# AWS Glue additional module psycopg2

Tags: aws-glue

using AWS Glue, I've created a job Glue version 2.0 with the parameters --additional-python-modules = psycopg2-binary and --python-modules-installer-option = --upgrade but it fails to import the module.

`com.amazonaws.services.glue.PythonModuleInstaller    [main]  Collecting psycopg2-binary  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/14/65/223a5b4146b1d5d5ab66f16ef194916a1ed9720da1f118d7bfb60b8f2bea/psycopg2-binary-2.9.1.tar.gz (380kB)    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:    running egg_info    creating pip-egg-info/psycopg2_binary.egg-info    writing pip-egg-info/psycopg2_binary.egg-info/PKG-INFO    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/psycopg2_binary.egg-info/dependency_links.txt    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/psycopg2_binary.egg-info/top_level.txt    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/psycopg2_binary.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'        Error: pg_config executable not found.        pg_config is required to build psycopg2 from source.  Please add the directory    containing pg_config to the $PATH or specify the full executable path with the    option:            python setup.py build_ext --pg-config /path/to/pg_config build ...        or with the pg_config option in 'setup.cfg'.        If you prefer to avoid building psycopg2 from source, please install the PyPI    'psycopg2-binary' package instead.        For further information please check the 'doc/src/install.rst' file (also at    <https://www.psycopg.org/docs/install.html>).`

What could be the cause?

Comment: I don't expect that you need the parameter ```--python-modules-installer-option = --upgrade```, have you tried it without that?

Comment: Yes I tried without --upgrade, same behavior. Using pg8000 it is imported without any problems

Answer (score 2):

Try to use an older version of psycopg2-binary. I had this same issue. So it would look like this **--additional-python-modules | psycopg2-binary==2.8.6**

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple approaches in order to develop GLUE jobs :

1. Spark with Scala
2. Spark with Python
3. Python Shell
4. Spark streaming

In our scenario we were using python shell for development purposes and faced similar issues .
Resolution :
Please try creating .egg file using Python version 3.6 [ currently .egg / .wheel created by v3.6 is only supported ] and place it in s3 folder and you can add reference to same file in Glue job parameters .

For reference you can refer :
https://helicaltech.com/external-python-libraries-aws-glue-job/
https://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2012/07/12/python-101-easy_install-or-how-to-create-eggs/

If you are using Spark shell please try creating Zip of library and follow the similar steps as suggested above .
In addition you can refer :

https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/glue-job-use-external-python-libraries/